# Is there a search addon for Firefox that allows to add GET/POST variables from current page?

Tags: firefox, search, context, productivity

What I am looking for is basically the Firefox equivalent to this Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selection-search/gipnlpdeieaidmmeaichnddnmjmcakoe

Now before everybody yells "Context Search", please have a closer look at the description of the Chrome extension (i.e. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selection-search/gipnlpdeieaidmmeaichnddnmjmcakoe/details). Two features make this extension unique:

1.) It can use hostname, path and GET parameters of the current site and use them in the query. So you could specify a search engine with a pattern like "`https://${currenthost}/${currentpath}/anotherpage.html?ding=${highlightedword}&foo=${valueof(foo)}`".

E.g. if my current site is "`http://myhost/mypath/mypage.html?foo=bar`" and I highlight a word on that page (e.g. "dong"), then the context search points to "`https://myhost/mypath/anotherpage.html?ding=dong&foo=bar`".

Plain genius, I am sure you get the idae. It allows you to save numerous clicks on clumsily designed web pages. Stuff that lied multiple clicks away is now at your immediate disposal.

2.) The search is not (only) available in the context menu but also in a floating menu which appears with every highlighting that you do on a page. Saves one additional click with every search. I have seen some Greasemonkey script doing that too, but could not find anything configurable.

Any suggestions?

I am open for anything that will work with Firefox. If there is no addon, then I would happily use some Window program like clicktoapp.com (which falls short on the URL parameters) or an AutoIt script etc.